# A question about how to learn Multivariable Calculus in depth

Tags: multivariable-calculus, book-recommendation

What subjects do I have to learn to understand in depth Multivariable Calculus and what books to use ? In the books that I have used some concepts as orientability and regularity of surfaces are not presented clearly and accurately. I need to formulate multivariable calculus problems, but I'm not sure about my full understanding of this subject.

Comment: How about single variable calculus? (Okay, maybe that was a tad too sarcastic...) =)

Comment: Zorich "Mathematical Analysis II"